# Dynamic Title change on the screen

Tags: react-native

I have a navigation code:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    <Stack.Screen name='Learning' component={Learning}
      options={{
        headerTransparent: true,
        title: 'Learning',
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      }} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

I use the Learning screen for two functional application screens:

- A
- B

On screen A, I have two buttons:

- `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Learning', { screen: 'Learning' })}/>`
- `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Learning', { screen: 'Repeats' })}/>`

Depending on this content, `{screen: 'Learning'}` is loading some other data

This screen has a title header

How do you make it load a different title depending on the button you click?

I can't find a solution how to do it for **Components built on functions and Hooks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options` prop can take a function and provide `{route, navigation}` object as an argument for you, so to use the `params` in the header, you can do this:

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Learning"
    component={Learning}
    options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.screen })}
/>
```

I'm not sure what difference the functional components and hooks make in this case, but in  case I misunderstood the question, you can use `useNavigation` and `useRoute` hooks in your functional components and do the same things that you do in classes.